# Collision Detection Function

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision

I have constructed this function to be able to check if two object are touching in a AABB collision type model but I can't quite figure out the logic or rather why it doesn't work.

```
function hitTest(x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2) {
    //x1, y1 = x and y coordinates of object 1 
    for (var x = 0; x < AliLength; x++) {
        x1 = AliensArrR1[x].getX();
        y1 = AliensArrR1[x].getY();
    }
    //w1, h1 = width and height of object 1
    w1 = 50;
    h1 = 18;
    //x2, y2 = x and y coordinates of object 2 (usually midpt)
    for (var x = 0; x < bullets.length; x++) {
        x2 = bullets[x].getX();
        y2 = bullets[x].getX();
    }
    // w2, h2 = width and height of object 2
    w2 = 3;
    h2 = 13;
    if ((x1 <= x2 && x1 + w1 >= x2) &&
    (y1 <= y2 && y1 + h1 >= y2) && (x2 <= x1 && x2 + w2) && (y2 <= y2 && y2 + h2))
        alert("Hit");
    else
        return false;
};
```

There are 12 images per each row and an array for each, I'm not worried about performance right now just want to make sure I can get it working on one and get the logic correct.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

edit: I'm trying to check if object one which has the width of 18 and 50 ever overlaps with my other object which has a width of 3 and height of 13, These never change only the x and y axis's change. I'm new to doing collision detection and after having a couple stabs at how to apply the logic of checking both the x and y on each to see if they intersect. I thought I would ask for some help as clearly I'm heading in the wrong direction.

![This is what I'm trying to achieve]:http://uploads.gamedev.net/monthly_06_2011/ccs-8549-0-64600400-1307074262.gif

Comment: You're using capitals as starting letters too generously, even within `alert()`. In JS only constructor function names should start with a capital.

Comment: I added the alert in after pasting from my IDE, But agreed coming from a different language I'm still getting used to the correct Syntax. This annoys me as much as it does you :)!

Comment: Well, I don't mind your convention, just mentioned, but `Alert()` will give you a reference error...

Comment: Updated my thread, It was not the same in my version.

Comment: I don't get it why you are receiving arguments and doing nothing with them. Also note that after the `for` loops, x1 and y1 values will be the last item on the ali array, same applies to the x2 y2 loop.

Comment: You really need to choose better names for variables. Naming everything `x` and `y`, even loop variables, and just adding numbers to it, can make even small code like this really hard to read.

Comment: Your condition looks odd. Why is there a check for `x1 <= x2` and `x2 <= x1` and `y2 <= y2`? What is `y2 + h2` accomplishing? I suggest breaking down your conditions and clarifying what they are supposed to do

Comment: Updated my original thread with my more clarification of my aims.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you refactor your code a bit. Keep the eight arguments, but do not assign anything to them in the function `hitTest` and do not reference any global variables or constants. Just compare the given coordinates and widths and return `true` if they overlap, `false` otherwise.

Test this function by feeding it some test cases. If you can't visualize in your head, draw a 2D grid and label the axes then draw arbitrary rectangles. Pick two that are not overlapping, give them to your function, and check that it returns false. Pick two that are overlapping, give them to your function, and check that it returns true. Pick two that are just touching, feed them to your function, and check that it returns what you would like it to return. Repeat until you are confident your code is correct.

Then use this function to implement another function which goes through all the aliens and all the bullets and checks using `hitTest` if any of them collide. It should give `18`, `50`, etc. as the width and height. If the coordinates refer to the centre of the object, you may need to offset them so that they refer to the top right corner.

**Hint**

If you find it hard to do the collision checking in 2D, make a simpler function which takes two 1D line segments `(x1, w1, x2, w2)` and determines if they overlap. The 2D case can be broken down into two 1D checks: the objects should overlap both horizontally and vertically.

**Final solution**

```
x1 + w1 >= x2 && x2 + w2 >= x1 && y1 + h1 >= y2 && y2 + h2 >= y1
```

Comment: This was defiantly the kind of answer I was looking for, I'm gunna sketch this up on a whiteboard and give it a go that way.. should of thought of it earlier!

Comment: I think a big reason as to why I'm finding this more difficult is in how I'm implementing the images which I wish to check the collision on, By adding them into an array I'm not sure how to get the Position values into this algorithm without using a for loop.

Comment: The trick is to use nested for-loops: `for (each alien) { for (each bullet) { if (hitTest(current alien and current bullet)) { ... } } }`

Comment: This is currently what I have `((x1 >= x2 + w1 && x2 <= x1 + w2) && (y1 >= y2 + w1  && y2 <= y1 + w2))` Doesn't seem to be working :/

Comment: It should be `x1 + w1 >= x2 && x2 + w2 >= x1` (the right edge of one segment should be further to the right than the left edge of the other segment). Same for `y`.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly done, buuuut...

Given `w1` width of, `h1` height of, `x1` X position of, `y1` Y position of Object 1, and idem for `x2`, `y2`, `w2`, `h2` on Object 2:

The conditional should be OR between conditions and I bet there are some typos in your vertical part. Commented version:

```
if (
    // Horizontal collision
    // Does right edge of 1 collide with left edge of 2? Only when 1 to the left of 2
    (x1 <= x2 && x1 + w1 >= x2) ||
    // Does left edge of 1 collide with right edge of 2? Only when 2 to the left of 1
    (x2 <= x1 && x2 + w2 >= x1) ||

    // Vertical collision
    // Does bottom edge of 1 collide with top edge of 2? Only when 1 above 2
    (y1 <= y2 && y1 + h1 >= y2) ||
    // Does top edge of 1 collide with bottom edge of 2? Only when 2 above 1
    (y2 <= y1 && y2 + h2 >= y1)
) {
    // hit
}
```

Comment: This code is incorrect. Test it with `(x1, y1) = (0, 0), (x2, y2) = (10, 0), w1 = h1 = w2 = h2 = 4`. They do not overlap, but it says they hit.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct but like that:

```
function hitTest(x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2) {    
  if (((x1 <= x2 && x1 + w1 >= x2) || (x2 <= x1 && x2 + w2 >= x1)) && ((y1 <= y2 && y1 + h1 >= y2) || (y2 <= y1 && y2 + h2 >= y1)))
    return true; 
  else
    return false;    
}
```